# Swift can't get text of label even though the same expression

Tags: swift, uilabel

im programming a calculator app as an exercise project.
I have already used the text of the label before via

```
calculatorLabel.text
```

Eventhough I use exactly the same expression in another function, I always get 0 instead of the actual text inside it. I seriously do not understand why that happens. I have already tried using debug mode and stuff but it doesn't work.

here ar the two functions (shortened):

```
@IBAction func operationButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let operation = sender.currentTitle!

    lastSender.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBlue
    lastSender = sender

    sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange

    //a switch would be here(deleted)

    isTyping = false
    let currentNumber = Double(calculatorLabel.text!)!

    a = currentNumber

}

@IBAction func changeStateButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let operation = sender.currentTitle!
    let displayedNumber = Double(calculatorLabel.text!)!
    var displayedText = self.calculatorLabel.text!

    if operation == "+/-"{
        if operation.prefix(1) == "-" {
            displayedText.remove(at: displayedText.startIndex)
        }
        else{
            displayedText = "-" + String(displayedNumber)
        }
    }
    else if operation == "%"{
        displayedText = String(displayedNumber/100)
    }

    calculatorLabel.text = displayedText
}
```

the top one gets the text while the bottom one doesn't...
thank you very much in advance for trying to help me!

Answer (score -2):

I found the answer...

It seems the connection between it and the code was somehow messed up.
To all who have the same problem: right click the component in the storyboard and check the connections!